# Separate ul according to an element css

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, underscore.js

I have a problem with a development, all I get is a list this way

this is my code ASPX

```
<style> .level1 { font-weight:bold !important; } </style> <asp:Menu ID="MenuHijosPro" runat="server" Width="100%" StaticDisplayLevels="2" > </asp:Menu>
```

This is plain html result

```
<div id="MenuHijosPro" style="float: left;">
  <ul class="level1 static" tabindex="0" role="menu" style="position: relative; width: auto; float: left;">
    <li role="menuitem" class="static" style="position: relative;"><a class="level1 static" href="Default.aspx" tabindex="-1">CARPETA PEDAGOGICA</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem" class="static" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 static" href="frm_ListaSilabo.aspx" tabindex="-1">Silabo</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem" class="static" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 static" href="frm_AsistenciaAsignatura.aspx" tabindex="-1">Asistencia Alumno</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem" class="static" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 static" href="Frm_Reg_Notas.aspx" tabindex="-1">Notas Alumno</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem" class="static" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 static" href="frm_NotaFinal.aspx" tabindex="-1">Acta de Notas</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem" class="static" style="position: relative;"><a class="level1 static" href="Default.aspx" tabindex="-1">CONTROL DE ASISTENCIA </a></li>
    <li role="menuitem" class="static" style="position: relative;"><a class="level2 static" href="frm_EjecucionHoras.aspx" tabindex="-1">Mi Asistencia</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But I want to create an Accordion with bootstrap separate the lists using title the first item "level1" and then the content that appears later until the next "level1"

[image]

I hope you can help me. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried using the collapse class?

Comment: If you try to put the css of the colapse, but the system that is used generates this type of response in that format, it does not give space to personalization of the exit code.

Comment: So you can't change the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

- Is this something closer to what you are looking for?
- I followed the exaample from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div id="MenuHijosPro" class= "row">
<div class = "col-md-12">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info col-md-12" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">CARPETA PEDAGOGICA</button>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse class= "col-md-12">
    <li role="menuitem" class="static" ><a class="level2 static" href="frm_ListaSilabo.aspx" tabindex="-1">Silabo</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem" class="static" ><a class="level2 static" href="frm_AsistenciaAsignatura.aspx" tabindex="-1">Asistencia Alumno</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem" class="static" ><a class="level2 static" href="Frm_Reg_Notas.aspx" tabindex="-1">Notas Alumno</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem" class="static" ><a class="level2 static" href="frm_NotaFinal.aspx" tabindex="-1">Acta de Notas</a></li>
</div>
</div>
<div class = "col-md-12">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info col-md-12" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1">CONTROL DE ASISTENCIA</button>
<div id="demo1" class="collapse class= "col-md-12">
    <li role="menuitem" class="static"><a class="level2 static" href="frm_EjecucionHoras.aspx" tabindex="-1">Mi Asistencia</a></li>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I want to have something like this, but my code is as follows:

`<style>
                   .level1
                   {
                       font-weight:bold !important;
                   }
               </style>
               <asp:Menu ID="MenuHijosPro" runat="server" Width="100%" StaticDisplayLevels="2" >
               </asp:Menu>`

Then when sending to generate me sends as a result what I publish in my question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I fail you understand your comment. Could you please explain in detail. Edit your question to explain what you did and what you expect. Thanks